# How to 'self-host' fonts on github-pages - website fonts not loading

Tags: css, github, fonts, font-face, github-pages

I have launched my portfolio website on Github recently, unfortunately, my fonts are not loading on my GitHub portfolio. How do I 'self-host' the fonts on Github?

I have researched and came across this link, but I'm not sure how to implement it or if it is an effective way to solve my problem.

https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typefaces

Here is my @font-face css code:

```
@font-face {

   font-family: 'et-line';
   src:url('../fonts/et-line.eot');
   src:url('../fonts/et-lined41d.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/et-line.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/et-line.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/et-line.svg#et-line') format('svg');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code block looks no problem.

Are you sure the relative path is correct or place your font files properly?

or did you import this file into your `main.css`?

or changing the relative path to absolute path: like `src:url('../fonts/et-line.eot');` to `src:url('{{ site.url }/assetss/fonts/et-line.eot');`

or if you set multiple fonts for an element and wanna know which one effected, you could use Firefox to inspect the element, an underline showing under the effected font name. (Chrome doesn't have this feature.)

Comment: @MarlaTarrant  I updated my answer, try to use absolute path